# Opencart 1.5 How to add pdf download link in the footer of main page

Tags: opencart

I have been trying to figure out how to add the a pdf download link at my footer of the main page. I still can figure it out. I have been doing a lot of searching for sources I am yet to find it. Can anybody help with it by guiding me step by step please?

Comment: Do you know the location or url of your pdf?

Comment: Yes sir, its located at the download folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your catalog/controller/common/footer.php

```
    if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {
        $data['base'] = $this->config->get('config_ssl');
    } else {
        $data['base'] = $this->config->get('config_url');
    }


    $data['pdf_url'] = $data['base']. '/path_of_download_folder/pdf_file_name.pdf';
```

In your catalog/view/theme/theme_name/template/common/footer.tpl add the below code at the relevant place

To view in new tab:

```
<a href="<?php echo $pdf_url;?>" target="_blank">PDF</a>
```

Or to download:

```
<a href="<?php echo $pdf_url;?>" download>PDF</a>
```